# using knockout to set css class with an if condition

Tags: knockout.js

I want to set a bootstrap css class to a span with if condition (up to the binded value).
I have `isApproved` field in a list, I want to see the field with 'label-success' class when its active and 'label-important' class when its inactive

I added this line, but all the time it's taking the first class

```
data-bind="
    text: isApproved,
    css: isApproved = 'true' ? 'label label-important' : 'label label-important'"
```

Is it possible in the html or I should add a computed field on my VM?

Comment: Can you add the code you're working with? JS & HTML? Preferably in a jsfiddle or something.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If I understood you right, this is the binding you are looking for.

```
 data-bind="text: isApproved, css: {
    'label' :  true,
    'label-success' :  isApproved(),
    'label-important':  !isApproved()
 }"
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks , I didn't pay attention to the () with the isApproved property

Answer (score 46):

Ternary operator example

```html
<span class="label"
    data-bind="text: isApproved,
               css: isApproved() == true ? 'label-success' : 'label-important'">
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks , I didn't pay attention to the () with the isApproved property

Comment: This is a more elegant solution. Congrats.

Comment: Important to use this solution: in my case, the `isApproved()` function is expensive and should not be evaluated more than absolutely necessary

Comment: will it work runtime ? like play/pause button toggle ?